# React setting state inside List of list on a const instead of a state

Tags: reactjs

Basic React Web Application

Application:

Rendering out contact with hover on button using onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave.

Issue:

Not able to change the state of Hover

Addon:

How do I change the state of Hover from true to false inside the Team const?
Im new to react.

I understand simple way to change state but this is kinda complex for me.

```
const Team = [
  {
    Position: "Symposium General Chair",
    Group: [
      {
        Name: ["DUmmy nam"],
        Contact: ["222222222222"],
        Hover: false
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Position: "Symposium Chairs",
    Group: [
      {
        Name: ["DUmmy namexx"],
        Contact: ["33333333333"],
        Hover: false
      },
      {
        Name: ["DUmmy namexxcxzczx"],
        Contact: ["2222222222"],
        Hover: false
      },
      {
        Name: ["DUmmy namexca"],
        Contact: ["11111111111"],
        Hover: false
      }
    ]
  }
];

//Not important but to split the array into 2
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size) {
  var index = 0;
  var arrayLength = myArray.length;
  var tempArray = [];

  for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
    let myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index + chunk_size);
    tempArray.push(myChunk);
  }

  return tempArray;
}

//Extracted focus code here
    {chunkArray(Team, 2).map((col, i) => (
                <div className="row" key={i}>
                  {col.map(_Team => (
                    <div key={_Team.Position} className="w-50 ">
                      <h5>
                        <span className="badge badge-pill badge-info col-sm ">
                          {_Team.Position}
                        </span>
                      </h5>
                      {_Team.Group.map(_Group => (
                        <h6 key={_Group.Name} className="col-sm ">
                          {_Group.Name}

                          {!_Group.Hover ? (
                            <button
                              type="button"
                              className="btn close"

          //Problem is here how do I change the hover state to true?
                              onMouseEnter={_Group.Hover.setState(
                                (Hover = true)
                              )}

         //Problem is here how do I change the hover to false?
                              onMouseLeave={_Group.Hover.setState(
                                (Hover = false)
                              )}
                            >
                              O
                            </button>
                          ) : (
                            <div style={letterStyle} className="close">
                              {_Group.Contact}
                            </div>
                          )}
                        </h6>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              ))}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're utilizing Component state, so the method setState would not work effectively in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're kind of missing the point of using React.  The JSON structure is pretty confusing and I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but take a look at the CodeSandbox below, as I think you should be utilizing the [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) updater like so:

```
  handleOnMouseEnter(teamIndex, groupIndex) {
    console.log("entering teamIndex/groupIndex: ", teamIndex, groupIndex);
    this.setState(state => {
      state.teams[teamIndex].Group[groupIndex].Hover = true;
      return state;
    });
  }
```

I think the snippet I've put together should show you better how to properly do what you're attempting with React:

https://codesandbox.io/s/7wlx56j3r1

Comment: Thats not doing anything for me. Is there supposed to be a hover effect?

Comment: @GaryCarlyleCook -- look in your console while hovering.  You can conditionally add a class, which would give some sort of visual indication, but in this case I didn't do that.